# What is the difference between frame and null in showMessageDialog in Java?

Tags: java, swing

Say i have an object of the JFrame class as frame

I was wondering what is the difference between

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message)
```

and

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,message)
```

to print something out.Both give the same result and they pop up at the same place.So i was wondering what is really the difference between these two? What happens actually in background differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When providing the frame or any other component the option pane will pop up at the middle of the component. However if you are providing null then it will pop up at the middle of your screen.

In your case I guess your Jframe is of your screen size. So if you reduce your frame size and start it at the default location i.e top left corner then you may see the difference.

Answer (score 5):

```
// the dialog is centered on the desktop
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message)

// the dialog is centered on the frame
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,message)
```

Answer (score 4):

From java documentation:

> parentComponent
>   Defines the Component that is to be the parent of this dialog box. It is used in two ways: the Frame that contains it is used as the Frame parent for the dialog box, and its screen coordinates are used in the placement of the dialog box. In general, the dialog box is placed just below the component. This parameter may be null, in which case a default Frame is used as the parent, and the dialog will be centered on the screen (depending on the L&F).

For more information read the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

Answer (score 2):

Both will do almost the [same stuff](http://alvinalexander.com/java/joptionpane-showmessagedialog-examples-1)

> In that example my first argument to the JOptionPane showMessageDialogmethod is a frameobject (which presumably is an instance of a JFrame). If for some reason you don't have a reference to JFrameor JWindow instance, you can make that field null, and still display the identical JOptionPane dialog,

And from [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29)

> parentComponent - determines the Frame in which the dialog is displayed; if null, or if the parentComponent has no Frame, a default Frame is used.

Default frame is ,your  main `screen`.